# Htaccess Redirect based on URL and query string

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

In my .htaccess I'm trying to redirect the following page:

/category/item?id=81

To the following URL:

/category

This is where I got to far (it's at the top of my mod rewrites):

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/category/item$
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=81$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mywebsite/category? [L,R=301]
```

However it's not redirecting the page. Just wondering if there's anything I need to add to this to get it to work?

Comment: Probably the url or the query string does not end with the given pattern. Remove the $ to search from the beginning of the string only, instead of the whole string (until it ends)

Comment: Your rule works fine for me. Try clearing your browser cache or use a different browser to test the url.

Comment: Also adding `RewriteEngine on` might help

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^id=81$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^category/item$ /category? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^id=81$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^category/item$ http://mywebsite//category? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Use a fresh browser in incognito mode to test it.

Comment: Thank you for this :) I managed to get a solution working shortly after I posted my question (see below), but these are helpful to know for the future

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me (I solved it before the answers above were posted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/category/item$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=81
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ category? [L,R=301]
```